# I am working on choosing an ideal anode for salt water battery.

Tags: battery-chemistry

Can anyone tell me how to justify this anode is the best compared to other?  ALso, why the discharge capacity decrease with C rate?

what does cyclability  and rate capability means?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Which anode? Please also give some context or links to the cyclability and rate capability.

Answer (score 1):

This 62 page paper goes into saltwater design details. Do some reading, tell us what you discover.

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1711/1711.10457.pdf